# Java Generics: Static method of a specific argument Type does not match the Functional Interface

Tags: java, generics, java-8, covariance, method-reference

The first assignment below doesn't compile, but I am not sure why, the method signature of the static method matches the functional method signature albeit it is not using type arguments. The second line compiles fine even though it is the same signature except for the type parameterization.

What is the reasoning behind this?

```
public class GenericSample<T> {
    public static void staticLambdaMtd(Integer a) {
            
    }   

    public static<X> void staticLambdaMtd2(X a) {
            
    }  

    // Funca<T> fa1 = GenericSample::staticLambdaMtd;//does not compile !

    Funca<T> fa = GenericSample::staticLambdaMtd2;//does compile !      
}
    
interface Funca<A> {
    public void funct(A a);
}
```

Comment: The variable `fa1` should be of type `Funca<Integer>` for the first expression to compile. The compiler would expect a function having generic type `T` on the right side of the expression (some type that would be defined while class `GenericSample` will get instantiated), but you're trying to utilize a method reference that is capable to work only with `Integer` type (not with an arbitrary type). Therefore, the compiler will disallow this assignment.

Answer (score 6):

You are mixing a generic parameter `T` and a type `Integer`. That wouldn't work because `T` and `Integer` are different types.

Generics are *invariant*. That means you can assign to a `List<Person>` only another list having the same generic parameter, i.e. `Person` (not `Integer`, `Cat` or `T`). Similarly, we can't assign `Funca<Integer>` to a variable of type `Funca<T>`.

*For more information, have a look at this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) provided by Oracle.*

A function created using a static method `staticLambdaMtd(Integer a)` is assignable only to a variable of type `Funca<Integer>`, but not `Funca<T>` - i.e. function of some arbitrary type, because only `Integer` type would match the method signature, but not any type (like `String`, `Cat`, `BigDecimal`) that would be defined while class `GenericSample` will get instantiated.

The second statement compiles fine, because it doesn't expect any specific type. `X` is only a placeholder, as well as `T`. And expression `GenericSample::staticLambdaMtd2` should be classified as a so-called [*poly expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2), i.e. because you're not providing a type compiler needs to infer it from the assignment context.

Therefore, the expression `GenericSample::staticLambdaMtd2` would be inferred as being of type `Funca<T>` and the second statement will compile fine.

All assignments shown below are valid:

```
// expression on the right could represent only `Funca<Integer>`

Funca<Integer> fa1 = GenericSample::staticLambdaMtd;


// expression on the right can be succefully inferred to 
// a function of any type based on the assingment context on the left

Funca<T> fa = GenericSample::staticLambdaMtd2;      
Funca<String> fa = GenericSample::staticLambdaMtd2;
Funca<BigDecimal> fa = GenericSample::staticLambdaMtd2;
```

***Note*** that expression `GenericSample::staticLambdaMtd2` can be turned from a *poly expression* into a *"standalone form"* by providing a generic parameter (*in fact, method references by definition provided in the specification are **always poly expressions**, therefore I've used "standalone" in quotation marks meaning only that assignment context will be ignored*).

And that we how can break it:

```
// that will not compile for the same reason as the the firt statement doesn't compile

Funca<T> fa3 = GenericSample::<Integer>staticLambdaMtd2;
```

Comment: @Holger BTW I was expecting that someone propose a better explanation when a method reference is being provided with an explicit generic parameter `Type::<Something>method`. According to the specification, method references are always poly expressions, but in this case there's nothing to infer, the compiler still has to check where the provided parameter matches the method signature and whether the reference fits in to the context. In this case, everything will seem to work like in Java 7, where there were no poly expressions (sure, and no method references as well).

Comment: @Holger Why method reference with an explicit type argument still should be treated as poly expression?

Comment: It seems, you wrote `@Holger` after my comments were removed, so I didn’t get a notification. • A method reference is an expression which always evaluates to some instance of a functional interface. Since this result interface type is always given as target type, in other words, a method reference has no type of its own, a method reference is always a poly expression.